# Is it possible to limit the number of lines of code in a method without empty line breaks between them with CheckStyle?

Tags: java, checkstyle

I want check style to limit code like this:

```
String someVariable = "value";
int val = getNum(someVariable);
SomeObject obj = someObject.callIt(val);
doSomethingUnrelated();
int result = anotherObject.doIt(
    1,
    obj,
    AnEnum.VALUE
);
return result;
```

That code has too many lines in a row with no separation. I want it to throw a warning.

But I also want to allow it if it's args to a method call that has a lot of parameters:

```
int result = anotherObject.doIt(
    1,
    obj,
    AnEnum.VALUE,
    23,
    someOtherObject,
    "/some/file/path",
    "This is a lot of params"
);
```

Is it possible to do both of those requirements in CheckStyle?

Comment: This seems like code style that's easier and more productive to self-enforce rather than statically analyze. I don't believe checkstyle allows this sort of check.

Comment: Nope, you'll have to write your own check.

Answer (score 0):

> code has too many lines in a row with no separation

There is nothing this specific in Checkstyle. The closest check is [`MethodLengthCheck`](http://checkstyle.sourceforge.net/config_sizes.html#MethodLength) which counts max lines in a method. The only difference is you want to reset the count to 0 if an empty line is found thus only printing violations on more than X statements in a row with no line separation. [You will have to write your own check](http://checkstyle.sourceforge.net/writingchecks.html), and could use `MethodLengthCheck` as a foundation if you don't want to start from scratch.

If you are successful writing your check, feel free to [contribute it to sevntu](https://github.com/sevntu-checkstyle/sevntu.checkstyle).

> want to allow it if it's args to a method call that has a lot of parameters

This requirement may not be as easy to accomplish since method calls could be embedded in the statement, but you can suppress these situations if you can't make your check find and ignore them.